# Prevent weird eChart animation after setOption

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using eCharts to generate a graph. I used the `setOption` method of eCharts to enable/disable label based upon the zoom level with the following code:

```js
myChart.on("graphRoam", () => {
    const customOptions = myChart.getOption();
    if (
      customOptions.series[0].zoom >= showLabelsAtZoomLevel &&
      !customOptions.series[0].label.show
    ) {
      customOptions.series[0].label.show = true;
      myChart.setOption(customOptions, {
        notMerge: {
          silent: true,
        },
        lazyUpdate: true,
      });
    } else if (
      customOptions.series[0].zoom < showLabelsAtZoomLevel &&
      customOptions.series[0].label.show
    ) {
      customOptions.series[0].label.show = false;
      myChart.setOption(customOptions, {
        notMerge: {
          silent: true,
        },
      });
    }
})
```

On crossing the `showLabelsAtZoomLevel` threshold, the graph weirdly animates into the canvas. Please check this [video example of the animation which occurs on zoom-in and zoom-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMJFP.jpg).

I have already tried setting `animation` to false using `myChart.setOption({animation: false}), but it did not yield fruitful result.

**EDIT**: After @Ameredev comment, I aggressively set all animation parameter that I found in `myChart.getOption()` to `false`. The followig is the output of `myChart.getOption` after making the changes:

```json
{
    "animation": false,
    "stateAnimation": false,
    "aria": {
        "show": true,
        "description": "This is a force-oriented graph chart that depicts the relationship between ip nodes.",
        "enabled": true,
        "label": {
            "description": "This is a force-oriented graph chart that depicts the relationship between ip nodes.",
            "enabled": true,
            "general": {
                "withTitle": "This is a chart about \"{title}\"",
                "withoutTitle": "This is a chart"
            },
            "series": {
                "single": {
                    "prefix": "",
                    "withName": " with type {seriesType} named {seriesName}.",
                    "withoutName": " with type {seriesType}."
                },
                "multiple": {
                    "prefix": ". It consists of {seriesCount} series count.",
                    "withName": " The {seriesId} series is a {seriesType} representing {seriesName}.",
                    "withoutName": " The {seriesId} series is a {seriesType}.",
                    "separator": {
                        "middle": "",
                        "end": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "allData": "The data is as follows: ",
                "partialData": "The first {displayCnt} items are: ",
                "withName": "the data for {name} is {value}",
                "withoutName": "{value}",
                "separator": {
                    "middle": ", ",
                    "end": ". "
                }
            }
        },
        "decal": {
            "decals": [
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        1,
                        0
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        2,
                        5
                    ],
                    "symbolSize": 1,
                    "rotation": 0.5235987755982988
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "symbol": "circle",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        [
                            8,
                            8
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            8,
                            8,
                            0
                        ]
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        6,
                        0
                    ],
                    "symbolSize": 0.8
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        1,
                        0
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        4,
                        3
                    ],
                    "rotation": -0.7853981633974483
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        [
                            6,
                            6
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            6,
                            6,
                            0
                        ]
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        6,
                        0
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        [
                            1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            6
                        ]
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        1,
                        0,
                        6,
                        0
                    ],
                    "rotation": 0.7853981633974483
                },
                {
                    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
                    "symbol": "triangle",
                    "dashArrayX": [
                        [
                            9,
                            9
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            9,
                            9,
                            0
                        ]
                    ],
                    "dashArrayY": [
                        7,
                        2
                    ],
                    "symbolSize": 0.75
                }
            ],
            "show": false
        }
    },
    "backgroundColor": "#282222",
    "darkMode": "auto",
    "colorBy": "series",
    "color": [
        "#5470c6",
        "#91cc75",
        "#fac858",
        "#ee6666",
        "#73c0de",
        "#3ba272",
        "#fc8452",
        "#9a60b4",
        "#ea7ccc"
    ],
    "gradientColor": [
        "#f6efa6",
        "#d88273",
        "#bf444c"
    ],
    "textStyle": {
        "fontFamily": "sans-serif",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "normal"
    },
    "animationDuration": 1000,
    "animationDurationUpdate": 500,
    "animationEasing": "cubicInOut",
    "animationEasingUpdate": "cubicInOut",
    "animationThreshold": 2000,
    "progressiveThreshold": 3000,
    "progressive": 400,
    "hoverLayerThreshold": 3000,
    "useUTC": false,
    "series": [
        {
            "layout": "force",
            "label": {
                "show": true,
                "color": "#fff",
                "position": "top",
                "formatter": "{b}"
            },
            "labelLayout": {
                "hideOverlap": true
            },
            "force": {
                "gravity": 0.1,
                "edgeLength": [
                    20,
                    60
                ],
                "repulsion": 120,
                "initLayout": null,
                "friction": 0.6,
                "layoutAnimation": true
            },
            "roam": true,
            "draggable": true,
            "legendHoverLink": true,
            "emphasis": {
                "focus": "none",
                "lineStyle": {
                    "color": "#3acc38",
                    "opacity": 1
                },
                "scale": true,
                "label": {
                    "show": true
                },
                "edgeLabel": {}
            },
            "nodeStyle": {
                "color": "#ffebc4"
            },
            "linkStyle": {
                "width": 6,
                "color": "#1ba619"
            },
            "nodeSize": "15",
            "type": "graph",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "172.0.0.1",
                    "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#ffebc4"
                    },
                    "symbolSize": "15",
                    "emphasis": {},
                    "name": "172.0.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "172.0.0.2",
                    "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#ffebc4"
                    },
                    "symbolSize": "15",
                    "emphasis": {},
                    "name": "172.0.0.2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "172.0.0.5",
                    "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#ffebc4"
                    },
                    "symbolSize": "15",
                    "emphasis": {},
                    "name": "172.0.0.5"
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.1",
                    "target": "172.0.0.2",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                },
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.2",
                    "target": "172.0.0.1",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                },
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.1",
                    "target": "172.0.0.5",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                },
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.5",
                    "target": "172.0.0.1",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                },
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.2",
                    "target": "172.0.0.5",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                },
                {
                    "source": "172.0.0.5",
                    "target": "172.0.0.2",
                    "cost": 1,
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 6,
                        "color": "#1ba619"
                    },
                    "emphasis": {}
                }
            ],
            "z": 2,
            "coordinateSystem": "view",
            "circular": {
                "rotateLabel": false
            },
            "left": "center",
            "top": "center",
            "symbol": "circle",
            "symbolSize": 10,
            "edgeSymbol": [
                "none",
                "none"
            ],
            "edgeSymbolSize": 10,
            "edgeLabel": {
                "position": "middle",
                "distance": 5
            },
            "center": [
                384.22456881686037,
                355.6998144124949
            ],
            "zoom": 7.400249944258172,
            "nodeScaleRatio": 0.6,
            "itemStyle": {},
            "lineStyle": {
                "color": "#aaa",
                "width": 1,
                "opacity": 0.5
            },
            "select": {
                "itemStyle": {
                    "borderColor": "#212121"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "visualMap": [],
    "markArea": [],
    "markLine": [],
    "markPoint": [],
    "brush": [],
    "legend": [],
    "toolbox": [
        {
            "show": true,
            "iconStyle": {
                "borderColor": "#fff",
                "color": "none"
            },
            "feature": {
                "restore": {
                    "show": true,
                    "title": "Restore view",
                    "icon": "M3.8,33.4 M47,18.9h9.8V8.7 M56.3,20.1 C52.1,9,40.5,0.6,26.8,2.1C12.6,3.7,1.6,16.2,2.1,30.6 M13,41.1H3.1v10.2 M3.7,39.9c4.2,11.1,15.8,19.5,29.5,18 c14.2-1.6,25.2-14.1,24.7-28.5"
                },
                "saveAsImage": {
                    "show": true,
                    "title": "Save image",
                    "icon": "M4.7,22.9L29.3,45.5L54.7,23.4M4.6,43.6L4.6,58L53.8,58L53.8,43.6M29.2,45.1L29.2,0",
                    "type": "png",
                    "connectedBackgroundColor": "#fff",
                    "name": "",
                    "excludeComponents": [
                        "toolbox"
                    ],
                    "lang": [
                        "Right Click to Save Image"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "z": 6,
            "orient": "horizontal",
            "left": "right",
            "top": "top",
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "borderColor": "#ccc",
            "borderRadius": 0,
            "borderWidth": 0,
            "padding": 5,
            "itemSize": 15,
            "itemGap": 8,
            "showTitle": true,
            "emphasis": {
                "iconStyle": {
                    "borderColor": "#3E98C5"
                }
            },
            "tooltip": {
                "show": false,
                "position": "bottom"
            },
            "right": null,
            "bottom": null
        }
    ],
    "dataZoom": [],
    "axisPointer": [
        {
            "animation": false,
            "show": "auto",
            "z": 50,
            "type": "line",
            "snap": false,
            "triggerTooltip": true,
            "value": null,
            "status": null,
            "link": [],
            "animationDurationUpdate": 200,
            "lineStyle": {
                "color": "#B9BEC9",
                "width": 1,
                "type": "dashed"
            },
            "shadowStyle": {
                "color": "rgba(210,219,238,0.2)"
            },
            "label": {
                "show": true,
                "formatter": null,
                "precision": "auto",
                "margin": 3,
                "color": "#fff",
                "padding": [
                    5,
                    7,
                    5,
                    7
                ],
                "backgroundColor": "auto",
                "borderColor": null,
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "borderRadius": 3
            },
            "handle": {
                "show": false,
                "icon": "M10.7,11.9v-1.3H9.3v1.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,22H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.2h6.6z",
                "size": 45,
                "margin": 50,
                "color": "#333",
                "shadowBlur": 3,
                "shadowColor": "#aaa",
                "shadowOffsetX": 0,
                "shadowOffsetY": 2,
                "throttle": 40
            }
        }
    ],
    "tooltip": [
        {
            "confine": true,
            "padding": [
                5,
                12
            ],
            "textStyle": {
                "lineHeight": 5,
                "color": "#666",
                "fontSize": 14
            },
            "renderMode": "html",
            "className": "njg-tooltip",
            "axisPointer": {
                "animation": false,
                "type": "line",
                "axis": "auto",
                "animationDurationUpdate": 200,
                "animationEasingUpdate": "exponentialOut",
                "crossStyle": {
                    "color": "#999",
                    "width": 1,
                    "type": "dashed",
                    "textStyle": {}
                }
            },
            "z": 60,
            "show": false,
            "showContent": true,
            "trigger": "item",
            "triggerOn": "mousemove|click",
            "alwaysShowContent": false,
            "displayMode": "single",
            "showDelay": 0,
            "hideDelay": 100,
            "transitionDuration": 0.4,
            "enterable": false,
            "backgroundColor": "#fff",
            "shadowBlur": 10,
            "shadowColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)",
            "shadowOffsetX": 1,
            "shadowOffsetY": 2,
            "borderRadius": 4,
            "borderWidth": 1,
            "extraCssText": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `series[0].force.layoutAnimation` is set to `true`. If I set it to `false` then the problem gets a little fixed but we can no longer interact with the graph. Please check these videos for context:

- [series[0].force.layoutAnimation is set to `false`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK6we.jpg)
- [series[0].force.layoutAnimation is set to `true`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuDHN.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a full example code please ? Or sandbox link ? I think the issue doesn't come from this event.

Comment: We have a library built around echarts, [netjsongraph.js]](https://github.com/openwisp/netjsongraph.js). I have shared the logical code out of that library which is responsible for hiding/showing labels based on the zoom level.

Comment: Yes but I would like to see the whole "option" object of your chart. I think that your issue could be resolved by simply adding `animation: false` to each series

Comment: I can see for example in netjsongraph.render.js that each series has `animationDuration: 1000`, try removing that and put `animation: false` instead. (and do that everywhere you put animation in series if you don't want it). Also maybe add `customOptions.series[0].animation = false` in the code you shared.

Comment: Did you fix it already? Adding to what @Ameredev said, I set the animation of series to false like so

`let newOptionValues = {series: {animation: false}}`

`myChart.setOption(newOptionValues, opts);`